# why wont my link position with css?

Tags: css

```
<div id="link">
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>
</div>
<div id="foo">This is foo</div>
```

Im trying to position this using an external css stylesheet but it just stays in the same place even if i clear my cache. the css is the external stylesheet is below. the code above is being placed in a php file.

```
#link {
    position: relative;
    top: 1700px;
    left: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Is that your *complete* HTML and CSS?

Comment: Ok problem solved. had to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've provided looks fine. Are you sure the stylesheet is being included? Try inspecting the element and see if the styles are actually being applied.

Comment: yeah everything else in the stylesheet is read and executed except for this